# adding List view to a fragment shrinks layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an android activity which has three fragments and in one of the fragments I am using list view to display a list. The list can be long and the view needs to be scroll able. When the activity starts `onCreateView` method of all fragments is called. This is code for onCreateView method

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView;
        rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.files, container,false);
        WebService.getFiles((UsersPOJO)getArguments().getSerializable("currentUser"));
        return rootView;
    }
```

R.layout.files has listView.
The problem is when the activity starts layout of all the three fragments in that activity shrinks when a soft keypad pops up. I tried to set isScrollContainer to false on individual layout but it isn't working any solutions to this problem.

EDIT: R.layout.files

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/WhiteBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/filesLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noFiles"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edit_text_left_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edit_text_right_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/heading_top_margin"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filesListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: provide the layout for R.layout.files

Comment: @AkhilJain see the edits

Comment: what content do you have in list view, if there are no contents in it, it will most probably shrink
try to provide weight to listview and other views in the layout

Comment: @AkhilJain It will have list of files if files are present otherwise I will destroy it in the java class

Comment: provide layout weight, that might do the trick

Comment: @AkhilJain Nothing changed by layout_weight do you know why the layout shrinks

Comment: how are you loading the fragment, inside activity inside a placholder
also try to fill the adapter and set it in list view in `oncreateview` itself

Comment: Is there any EditText field in any of the fragments? That might be the cause of keyboard popping up on launch.

If so, remove the focus on any such EditText field.

Comment: @MandarKakade What about the user manually focused on the EditText to enter the text. I guess then layout will shrink I don't want it to happen if the user manually focused or it is programatically.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" might help in that case.

Add it to your activity inside manifest.

Comment: @MandarKakade Resolved the issue by setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: thnx...I knew it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`windowsSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond) attribute inside your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file. Just set `windowsSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`in your `<activity>`.

Comment: Resolved the issue by setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

Comment: can you have a look at this issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046646/buttons-in-listview-each-item-layout