# Buttons in ListView each item layout

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview and I am populating that list view from a ArrayList of custom objects.
This is the custom adapter code.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int a=position;


        FileHolder holder=null;
        View row = convertView;
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
            holder=new FileHolder();

            holder.file=files.get(position);
            holder.deleteButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
            holder.downloadButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);

            holder.deleteButton.setTag(holder.file);
            holder.downloadButton.setTag(holder.file);


            holder.fileName= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fileName);



            holder.fileName.setText(holder.file.getFileName());

        }
        else
        {
            holder=(FileHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        fPOJO=holder.file;
        final AsyncCall call=new AsyncCall();

        holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MODE=0;
                //call.execute(MODE);

            }
        });

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Delete File "+(String.valueOf(a))+"  "+fPOJO.getFileName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                MODE=1;
                //call.execute(MODE);

            }
        });


        return row;
    }

    public static class FileHolder{
    FilesPOJO file;
    TextView fileName;
    ImageButton downloadButton;
    ImageButton deleteButton;
}
```

There are two buttons one for file delete and other for file download. I have implemented on click listeners for these two buttons. The problem is when I click any button the fileName in the Toast message is different from the file name that I see on the screen display. For ex: I have 5 files with names

```
delete.png
upload.png
share.png
referesh.png
copy.png
```

and now when I click delete button corresponding to referesh.png file the toast pop ups and in that the file name is different than referesh.png.

how to resolve this issue.

EDITS:

This is how I set up this adapter

```
             FilesAdapter adapter=new FilesAdapter(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.file_list_view_item_row, Application.files);
            View header = (View) View.inflate(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.files_list_view_header_row, null);
            fileListHeading.inflate(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.files_list_view_header_row, null);
            filesListView.addHeaderView(header);
            filesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: is your fPOJO global?

Comment: @A.S. yes fPOJO is global variable. The Array list is list of these objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `fPOJO` variable when `onClick` is called it may have different value because after every getView you're changing it's value.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int a=position;


    final FileHolder holder;
    View row = convertView;
    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
        holder=new FileHolder();

        holder.file=files.get(position);
        holder.deleteButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        holder.downloadButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);

        holder.deleteButton.setTag(holder.file);
        holder.downloadButton.setTag(holder.file);


        holder.fileName= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fileName);



        holder.fileName.setText(holder.file.getFileName());

    }
    else
    {
        holder=(FileHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    final AsyncCall call=new AsyncCall();

    holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MODE=0;
            //call.execute(MODE);

        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Delete File "+(String.valueOf(a))+"  "+holder.fileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MODE=1;
            //call.execute(MODE);

        }
    });


    return row;
}
```

Just make `holder` final and get you're file name from it.

Comment: making holder final resolved the issue. Can you explain this I mean how fPOJO changed when button onClickListner is called.

Comment: Because before you're onClick call it will call more getView's so after every getView you're changing it's value to that row's fileName. You're fPOJO will point to the last called getView's holder and for every row fPOJO is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You store your list item in holder, this is your problem, ListView adapter creates as much convertViews as needed to fill the screen so if you have list of 10+ elements, only few will be added to row.

First of all don't store your list element in holder, you gave adapter method called `getItem(positoin)` to get it.

In your holder view store only references to layout views (TextView, Buttons etc) and `(if(row == null)` call findViewById on them and setTag.

Then set text, listeners outside the if statement, like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int a=position;


    FileHolder holder=null;
    View row = convertView;
    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
        holder=new FileHolder();

        holder.deleteButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        holder.downloadButton=(ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);

        holder.fileName= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fileName);

        row.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder=(FileHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    fPOJO= getItem(position);

    final AsyncCall call=new AsyncCall();

    holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(null);
    holder.downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MODE=0;
            //call.execute(MODE);

        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(null);
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Delete File "+(String.valueOf(a))+"  "+fPOJO.getFileName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MODE=1;
            //call.execute(MODE);

        }
    });


    return row;
}

public static class FileHolder{
    TextView fileName;
    ImageButton downloadButton;
    ImageButton deleteButton;
}
```

Also you can do some code optimalization, for example don't initialize LayoutInflater in `getView()` method, you can do it in adapter `Constructor`